# Game board with random game objects and difficulties

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have a game board which I want to fill with random game objects.
Lets give them the values `1...6` in an `int[10][10]` array.

The game should have different difficulties. The easier, the more of the same objects are allowed to be next to each other; the harder, the less of the same objects are next to each other (radius=2).

Example:
Lets assume a medium difficulty. 40% of the objects around an object (radius=2) can be of the same type.

```
 -000------
 00000-----
 00100-----
 00000-----
 -000------
```

Only 40% of the `0` are allowed to be of type `1`.

How can I create such a random array? Or is there a better way to implement difficulty in this case?

Comment: Generally I tackle this type of question by doing it myself on graph paper, by hand a few times. This gives me ideas on how to best implement it.  Can you give us some examples of good game boards?

Comment: An example would be the game Jelly Splash. In the early levels there are always some areas with 4 - 8 jellies of the same type next to each other. In later levels there are just a few areas with 3 - 5 jellies of the same type.  
Another example is Candy Crush. The first levels are full of 2 same types + 1 next to it. In harder levels this is less likely.

Comment: Every problem an be solved by [Monte Carlo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) :)

Answer (score 1):

The way i do it is to randomize the indexes and not the values itself..
So 40% of these would mean i would only loop 40% of the total count.
in your example this is what i would do..

```
int n = 20 * 0.4;
for(i=1; i<n; ++i){
    int r = GetRandomIndex();
    board[r] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this only works for 1 object type. The idea was that the whole array should be filled with 123456 with the 40% in radius in mind.

Comment: Then do it for all object type :/ i answered with the general concept to keep in mind, its up to you to implement it in your scenario. I mean, i wont do all the code for you :P just sayin

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
class Game {
    Game() {
        clearGameObjects();
    }
    void clearGameObjects() {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                gameObjects[i][j]=0;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        String s="";
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            List row=Arrays.asList(gameObjects[i]);
            s+="row "+i+" "+row+'\n';
        }
        return s;
    }
    void distributeObjects(int x,int y,double percent,int type) {
        clearGameObjects();
        gameObjects[x][y]=type;
        List<Point> withinRadius=new ArrayList<>(21);
        Point2D p1=new Point2D.Double(x,y);
        Point p;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
                if(p1.distance(p=new Point(i,j))<Math.sqrt(5))
                withinRadius.add(p);
            }
        System.out.println(withinRadius.size()+" points within radius: "+withinRadius);
        int placed=1;
        for(Point p2:withinRadius)
            if(p2.getX()!=x&&p2.getY()!=y) 
                if(placed/(double)withinRadius.size()<percent) {
                    gameObjects[p2.x][p2.y]=type;
                    placed++;
                }

        System.out.println("placed "+placed+" items, "+placed/(double)withinRadius.size()*100+"%");

    }
    final int n=10;
    Integer gameObjects[][]=new Integer[n][n];
}
public class So21541681 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game=new Game();
        System.out.println(game);
        game.distributeObjects(5,6,.40,1);
        System.out.println(game);
    }
}
```